# VBA dictionary, class 424 object required error

Tags: vba, class, dictionary, compiler-errors

This code is has an  424 object error.

```
   Dim singleKey As Variant

    For Each singleKey In thecollection.Keys()

        Debug.Print thecollection.Item(singleKey).Country

    Next singleKey
```

The error is caused by the debug.print line.

The country is part of a custom class.

I am at a lost.

Comment: No, this error is caused by `singleKey` returning a null object or a non-object from the `Dictionary`. Where are you filling `thecollection`?

Comment: I am passing in a dictionary from another sub.  The dictionary is there.  I can see it in the locals window.

Comment: If I remove the "Country", the code run and it returns the index number.

Comment: It looks as if you are treating the value as an object, while it just is a number. Can you provide us with some of the code that populates the dictionary?

Comment: I wasn't implying that the dictionary wasn't there. I'm saying the error is almost certainly because `thecollection.Item(singleKey)` is `Nothing`.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing the code that populates the dictionary. `.Country` is a member call that implies the dictionary is populated with objects that have a `Country` property. `.Item(singlekey)` returning a number points to the dictionary *not* being populated with object instances.

Comment: Ok, not *impossible*.

Comment: would it not be `thecollection(singlekey).country` ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that's an implicit default member call. `Item` is the default member, OP's code is just making it explicit.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, that's what i am getting at is it a(x) where x the number of `classes` in the dictionary, so key(x) should return item(x) a class, looks like this is not the case.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `Item` (whether implicit or explicit) takes a `Key` parameter, not an index.

Comment: Yes, `singleKey` is a key as it comes from the keys() array.   The OP hasnt got the dictionary set right, so it should be col("a")=class, col("b")=class.  So `thecollection(singlekey)` should return the item, the populated class.  As answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If I remove the "Country", the code run and it returns the index number.*

Then you are populating your dictionary with numbers, possibly due to inverting the `Key` and `Item` arguments to the `Dictionary.Add` method, but that's hard to tell without seeing that code.

"Object Required" means you're making a member call against something that isn't an object... like a number, or a string.

In order for `thecollection.Item(singleKey).Country` to succeed, you need to be populating `thecollection` (a very misleading name for a `Dictionary` BTW) with objects that have a `Country` property.

For example you'd have a `Thing` class module with this code:

```
Option Explicit
Private mCountry As String

Public Property Get Country() As String
    Country = mCountry
End Property

Public Property Let Country(ByVal value As String)
    mCountry = value
End Property
```

Then you'd be creating instances of that class, and populating the dictionary with them:

```
Dim thing1 As Thing
Set thing1 = New Thing
thing1.Country = "Canada"
thecollection.Add "foo", thing1 ' note: key first, then the item
```

Then your code would work. That said I realize this is examplified code, but iterating dictionary keys doesn't strike me as very efficient.

Comment: Yes, you were right!  I switched the key and item.  Now the code works.  Thank you so much.